# Threads - Mac vs Linux

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, macos, c++11

Great!

I just finished my implementation on Mac with `g++ / clang`

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.7.0
Thread model: posix
```

and tested my code on linux

`g++ (Debian 4.7.2-5) 4.7.2`

running a relatively simple threading operation. What worked on mac, fails on linux now with :

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
  what():  Operation not permitted
```

---

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <memory>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <stdexcept>


std::vector<std::thread> threads;
            std::vector<std::tuple<std::size_t, std::size_t>> parts = splitRows(maxNumberThreads, elements);

            for (std::size_t threadIndex = 0; threadIndex < maxNumberThreads; threadIndex++)
            {
                threads.push_back(std::thread(compute<T>,parts[threadIndex], numbers, std::ref(*this),std::ref(other),std::ref(target)));
            }
```

with the thread function defined as. Adding prints into `compute` it does not jump into the function at all... Any idea why this happens?

```
template<typename T>
void compute(const std::tuple<std::size_t,std::size_t> part,
            const std::size_t numbers, 
            const MyClass<T>& m1, 
            const MyClass<T>& m2,
            MyClass<T>& target){
```

I am compiling with

```
g++ -Wall main.cpp -o matrix.exe -std=c++11
```

but get the above runtime error. Any ideas how to fix this? I use std libraries only, nothing fancy...

Answer (score 2):

You are not linking pthread properly, try following command,

```
g++ -Wall main.cpp -o matrix.exe -pthread -std=c++11
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, worked. Thank you! So why does linux require pthread while mac can handle without?